# FileStream and it's buffering strategy

Tags: c#, io, filestream, bufferstrategy, bufferedstream

I've found out that there is no point in using BufferedStream in conjunction with FileStream as it has it's own buffering strategy. Yet, I was wondering about one thing:

```
FileStream fsWithBuffer = new FileStream("buf.dat", FileMode.OpenOrCreate,
                FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.None, 255);
            fsWithBuffer.WriteByte((byte)4);
            fsWithBuffer.Dispose();
```

This codes write one portion of byte into the specified file. Before that, this byte is kept in inner buffer, so I understand that if I didn't call Dispose() method, nothing would be written to the file.

Now, my question is: sometimes we don't want to put all of the data in a buffer of a FileStream, let's say it is meant to be only for small writes. Is there a possibility to put some data directly into the file associated with FileStream (without putting it earlier into inner buffer)?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you asking if you can use `FileStream` without a buffer? I don't see the point, you still have to dispose of the FileStream class.

Comment: You could always call `Flush`, although you won't get around the buffer this way (and I dont't see the point of wanting to do this without one).

Comment: Okay, I see. Thank You:) Anyway, I guess Flush is what I was looking for in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To sum up this question, as there was no official answer, here what I was looking for was the `Flush()` method. It saves the actual buffer to the file associated with FileStream and it was something I needed :)

Answer (score 3):

There is a Flag Enum `FileOptions.WriteThrough` value that can be passed to the `FileStream` constructor. It instructs the file stream to directly write to the underlying data storage without any buffering.

Comment: That's a good option, but now it is like the buffer is totally unneccessary, right? I mean, cause now it won't be used at all.

Comment: Yes, with this enum value applied, there is no buffer.

Comment: So what is the point of using it? I mean I could just create FileStream wihtout neither buffer nor this mentioned FileOption.